# More than one column groups causing width problems (min-width inheritance issues)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, column-width

Description
Problem: In an SSRS matrix report with multiple column groups - all of the column group's column widths are inheriting their min-widths from the first column group header.  So if the first parent column has more child group items than the other parents, all parent columns rendered as wide as the first resulting in a lot of wasted space.  The problem is occuring in even the simplest matrix reports.  See attachment for a wizard generated report showing this issue.

The issue is reproduced and is attached. [Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDUbm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the width of the column dynamically in SSRS matrix
[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047111/dynamic-matrix-width-to-always-equal-chart-width)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I'm still looking for a good solution.

But if you're integrating the report in a web page, a workaround I used is to override the min-width attributes with jQuery (my report is included in the web page with a ReportViewer control) :

In the css file:

```
.reportCell {
  min-width: 0 !important;
}
.reportCell div {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}
```

In the my ASPX :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { ReportStyle(); });
    });  

    function ReportStyle() {            
        $("[id^=VisibleReportContent] td").addClass("reportCell");
    }
</script>
```